# Anylogic Error Source Arrival Table in DB based Variable (Not Unique Database Value!)

Tags: database, simulation, anylogic

I have combo box in experiment screen with options : Lala, Poo, and Twinky. They will be input in variable as initial value. Lala, Poo, and Twinky. Also their database for arrival table :

[image]

I am trying to make source based on variable as below :

[image]

but I get this problem :

[image]

My objective is if I choose Lala, then Lala database arrival date will be used.
Hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: I should point out that the Teletubby is "Po", not "Poo". https://teletubbies.fandom.com/wiki/Po. The latter is — let us say — 'problematic'. Noone wants poo arriving into their process.

Answer (score 0):

In your dbase query wizard, select the "Single value" option. This will adjust the SQL code to use the `firstResult` query, which take the first entry it finds for your query, in your case the first time it finds "Lala".

Kudos on the data adjustments for the question :D

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help :D, sorry I don't know how to access this dbase query wizard, is it for Anylogic professional version? I use personal version and sorry I use internal table for database and not found this panel~

Comment: All in the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/query-builder.html#query-constructor . Works for any version

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants. He wants multiple arrivals (as a Source DB arrival table normally works), but restricted only to the rows for the 'grup' he specifies.

Comment: @StuartRossiter yes, could you help me for this please? thanks!